# Error Handling in Python that can detect program status

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, error-handling, ipython

I am really new to Python. I would like to create a **logical loop** for my python script where when the program stuck it will automatically jump to next line and continue the program.

Here is an example of my code which was a series of different combination of parameter values. I am aware that some combinations of parameter may crash the program that's why I want to have a Error Handling loop to keep the program running.

```
   ini_file="model-simulation fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=1,fnc=1,fr=1,fs=1.ini"; pytopkapi.run(ini_file)
   ini_file="model-simulation fL=0.1,fks=6,fno=1,fnc=1,fr=1,fs=1.ini"; pytopkapi.run(ini_file)
   ini_file="model-simulation fL=0.1,fks=11,fno=1,fnc=1,fr=1,fs=1.ini"; pytopkapi.run(ini_file)
   ini_file="model-simulation fL=0.1,fks=16,fno=1,fnc=1,fr=1,fs=1.ini"; pytopkapi.run(ini_file)
   ini_file="model-simulation fL=0.1,fks=21,fno=1,fnc=1,fr=1,fs=1.ini"; pytopkapi.run(ini_file)
   ini_file="model-simulation fL=0.1,fks=26,fno=1,fnc=1,fr=1,fs=1.ini"; pytopkapi.run(ini_file)
```

Sometimes it will have error messages like the following picture which stops the whole program. Could someone please help me out? [image]

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by a "logical loop".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I mean is this loop can detect if the program has stopped running or not? If has stopped, it can move to next line of the script.

Comment: What do you mean "stopped"? If the program has stopped, how can it do anything? If you are talking about error handling, read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Yeah, I think it might be called error handing in python. Never heard this term but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could catch the exceptions then continue after by doing:

```
ini_files = ["model-simulation fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=1,fnc=1,fr=1,fs=1.ini",
             "model-simulation fL=0.1,fks=6,fno=1,fnc=1,fr=1,fs=1.ini"]
for ini in ini_files:
    try:
        pytopkapi.run(ini)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)  # If you want to see your error
```

See [Error Handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) documentation